# C# WebView Doesn't Understand JavaScript Call of alert() (Windows 8 XAML Application)

Tags: c#, javascript, xaml, webview, windows-8

I'm writing a Windows 8 application in C# and XAML that hosts a Web page in a WebView.  The Web page makes calls to alert() and confirm(), but the WebView throws exceptions, saying, "'alert' is undefined," or "'confirm' is undefined."  Can alert() and confirm() be enabled, or do I need to write code to emulate their normal function?  And if I need to write them myself, how should I begin such an undertaking?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write code to enable them. Note that this is true in a HTML5 Win8 app as well as XAML.

For script that can access WinRT, you can use Windows.UI.Popup.MessageDialog:

```
(new Windows.UI.Popup.MessageDialog("Hello!", "Welcome")).showAsync().done(dismissedHandler)
```

Note that these are async, and **not** block execution.

For acquiring information form the user -- e.g text input from the user, there is nothing standard, and you'll need to create a new set of mark up for that.

Answer (score 5):

Alert and confirm will not work from a WebView.  You can use [WebView.ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) to receive an event from your script on your page and use that event to show a dialog box using the [MessageDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx).

In your script where you want the alert ...

```
window.external.notify('foo');
```

And use the example in the WebView.ScriptNotify method in your C#.

Comment: I have actually looked into those options already, but if I use window.external.notify for a confirm, how would I obtain its return value without major changes to my code?  For example, I could say, `var answer=window.external.notify("confirm('Yes or no?')")`
But how would I be able to stop the JavaScript, let the user answer, and then return the value to "answer"?

Comment: Perhaps WebView.InvokeScript will work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx

Comment: @user1325179 - Hi, I am facing a similar issue in WP 8.1.. did you find a solution to this ? I am able to show the message dialog with the confirm message , but how to return yes/no ?

Comment: @nipun.birla, I had to write HTML and JavaScript replacements.  For example, instead of a confirm() call, I had to make a form with yes and no buttons and then attach JavaScript functions to each button.  It's all asynchronous.  Making the switch was hard at first because I had to rewrite a lot of code that depended on a synchronous call to these sorts of functions, especially alert().

Comment: @user1325179 - Thanks for the reply, I found another solution in the meantime : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804380/cant-run-javascript-alerts-in-universal-apps-webview-at-payment-gateway O:)

Comment: @nipun.birla, that's still asynchronous, so I still needed to rewrite my code.  And I needed more versatility than Windows Phone's dialogs.  It's cool it worked for your case though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do some workaround. I did this and it worked for me.

```
       window.alert = function(__msg){window.external.notify(' + __msg + ');};
```

refer a similar question of mine for windows phone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843617/unable-to-show-alert-via-javascript-in-wp7-web-browser-control)